# Silverlight datagrid, style text in cells

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

What I am trying to do - I have a grid with some data, lots of it being text, what I want is to be able to hightlight a certain string within all that text....

I have the term...test
The text in the cell is "test 123 testing 123"

I want the word test to appear yellow, bold (or any other style I need).
I have done this with an asp.net grid by using the datarowbound event, and replacing the string "test" with some html that give the string the required style.

How would I go about doing that in a silverlight cell?

Maybe worth noting, the rows are added to the grid programmatically at runtime...

```
tcol = new DataGridTextColumn();
tcol.Binding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("class_property");
tcol.Header = "Header";
tcol.IsReadOnly = true;
dgResults.Columns.Add(tcol);
```

Thanks in anticipation...
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a pure Silverlight perspective, the way to style only parts of a text line (i.e. text in a textblock) is by using the Run element and adding the multiple Run elements to the textblock.

**CODE**

```
Run text = new Run();
                Run dates = new Run();
                Run comments = new Run();

                text.Text = y.User;
                dates.Text = " (" + y.TimeStamp.ToShortTimeString() + ")";
                comments.Text = ":"+y.Comment;

                dates.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

                rpconversation.Inlines.Add(text);
                rpconversation.Inlines.Add(dates);
                rpconversation.Inlines.Add(comments);
```

will provide text where the user and comments have the standard black text, and the dates will have blue text. You can read more about it on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189010(VS.95).aspx) site.

However, [this](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/3371.aspx) forum goes into how to change text elements through javascripting. Maybe have a read through it.

Comment: Excellent.  
Changing in js is not really something I want to get into.  Sounds a little hacky...

I would rather write a DataGridColumn or if possible change how the DataGridTextColumn renders to add in some Runs?? is possible or not?? 
Thx

Comment: You can add Runs in XAML (as shown in the MSDN link). However, it has to have a constant layout. So if the text is going to vary then you will have to add the Runs in code-behind.

Comment: code-behind is the only way I can do it...has to be done at runtime.  I'll read the article properly later - only had chance for a quick whizz at the mo...thx.

Answer (score 0):

There is a LoadingRow event handler which is part of the DataGrid.  You can do the same as your ASP .Net in this event.

Comment: Yeah I use that event for some other things...but can I style the content of the cell with html tags? I didn't think i could in silverlight?

Comment: I already have an application that uses this technique, so I'll adapt it to try and "style" the text.

Comment: I've tried to adjust the application and I can't get the Value to specify HTML and render as HTML.  It just displays the Value with the HTML.  I don't think this can be done.  Unless someone else in the community can help?

Comment: Yes I found the same, I am thinking of someway to maybe have a custom column and dynamically add different styled textblocks maybe?